# pytorch: Getting same result in each epoch

Tags: pytorch, training-data

I m try to train an rbf network... I used MNIST database. And pytorch framework...
The results are the same in each epoch...

The results....:

```
Epoch: 1  
Accuracy: 0.785     Loss: 2.435     Recall: 0.386   Precision: 0.258


Epoch: 2  
Accuracy: 0.785     Loss: 2.435     Recall: 0.386   Precision: 0.258


Epoch: 3  
Accuracy: 0.785     Loss: 2.435     Recall: 0.386   Precision: 0.258


Epoch: 4  
Accuracy: 0.785     Loss: 2.435     Recall: 0.386   Precision: 0.258
```

My Code... I think that the problem is somewhere in the linear layer. The model has no improve after the training epoch, maybe it's the linear layer. It seems like the weights no change...! But i don't know why...?

```
class RBF(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_layers, centers, sigmas):
        super(RBF, self).__init__()
        self.in_layers = in_layers
        self.centers = nn.Parameter(centers)
        self.sigmas = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(self.centers.size(0)))
        torch.nn.init.constant_(self.sigmas, sigmas)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, self.in_layers)
        size = [self.centers.size(0), x.size(0)]
        sigma = self.sigmas.view(-1).to(device)**2

        dists = torch.empty(size).to(device)

        for i,c in enumerate(self.centers):
            c = c.reshape(-1,c.size(0))
            temp = (x-c).pow(2).sum(-1).pow(0.5)
            dists[i] = temp

        dists = dists.permute(1,0)
        phi = torch.exp(-1*(dists/(2*sigma))) #gaussian
        return phi

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_layers, centers, sigmas):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.rbf_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        self.linear_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(len(in_layers) - 1):
            self.rbf_layers.append(RBF(in_layers[i], centers, sigmas))
            self.linear_layers.append(nn.Linear(centers.size(0), in_layers[i+1], bias = True))

    def forward(self, x):
        out = x
        for i in range(len(self.rbf_layers)):
            out = self.rbf_layers[i](out)
            out = F.sigmoid( self.linear_layers[i](out.float()) )
        return out


def training(engine, batch, device, model, criterion, optimizer):
    inputs, labels = batch[0].to(device), batch[1].to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return outputs, labels
```

Ofcourse the code continuous but i think these are enough to solve the problem(if you want smthing extra 'i m here').... Do you have any ideas???

and the training part of code....

```
def training(engine, batch, device, model, criterion, optimizer):
    inputs, labels = batch[0].to(device), batch[1].to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return outputs, labels

def nn_run1(batch, classes, dim, learning_rate, epochs, clusters):
    # ---Load Model's Parameters---
    train_loader, test_loader = data_loading(batch, shuffle=False)
    kmeans_input = train_loader.dataset.train_data
    kmeans_input = torch.reshape(kmeans_input.double(), (kmeans_input.size(0), -1))
    _, centers = Kmeans(kmeans_input, clusters)
    centers = centers.to(device)
    sigma = Sigmas(centers)
    layers = in_layers(dim, len(classes), layers = 1)

    # ---Model Setup---
    model = Net(layers, centers, sigma)
    model.cuda()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    print(model.parameters)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), learning_rate)
```

Comment: sigmoid out of the for loop perhaps ?

Comment: with sigmoid, or without is the same thing... i have tried to add sigmoid in both layers or none or one by one.... but the results still the same... not improve after each epoch!

Comment: Could you possibly show us your code that calls the training loop as well as the initialization of the variables?

Comment: @cmxu i add the code above... if you need smthing extra tell me

Comment: What are you using to loop over the epochs? If you you call the nn_run1 function in a for loop it would make a new model each time and that could cause you to be getting the same result each epoch? That's just a guess though.

Comment: no, i m not looping the nn_run1... i use ignite machine...!
`from ignite.engine import Events, Engine`

`trainer = Engine(partial(training, device=device, model=model, criterion=criterion, optimizer=optimizer))`
    
`tester = Engine(partial(testing, device=device, model=model))`

i m just call one time nn_run1....
if you want i can post the code of engine implementation but i don't think that is necessary cause it's working in another network fine!